# How to import an external model in vue.js using babylon js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, gltf, babylonjs

I am trying to import a gltf file in vue.js using babylon.js and add 3 dimensional view to the webpage. I can't figure out how to do that and the documentation online is pretty vague as well. Here's what I tried:
This is what I put in Hello.vue file

```
<div>
<h1> Hello </h1>
<Scene>
  <Box :position="[0, 0, 5]"></Box>
</Scene>
</div>
</template>

<script src = "./Hello.js">
</script>
```

This is what I put in Hello.js file

```
import vb from 'vue-babylonjs';
import Hello from './Hello.vue';

Vue.use(vb);

new Vue({
  components: { Hello },
  render: c => c('Hello'),
}).$mount('#app');


var delayCreateScene = function () {
    // Create a scene.
    var scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);

    // Create a default skybox with an environment.
    var hdrTexture = BABYLON.CubeTexture.CreateFromPrefilteredData("../assets/magic_book_of_eden/textures/material_0_baseColor.png", scene);
    var currentSkybox = scene.createDefaultSkybox(hdrTexture, true);

    // Append glTF model to scene.
    BABYLON.SceneLoader.Append("../assets/magic_book_of_eden/", "scene.gltf", scene, function (scene) {
        // Create a default arc rotate camera and light.
        scene.createDefaultCameraOrLight(true, true, true);

        // The default camera looks at the back of the asset.
        // Rotate the camera by 180 degrees to the front of the asset.
        scene.activeCamera.alpha += Math.PI;
    });

    return scene;
};
```

If possible, could someone explain using an example how that could be done? I am getting the gltf model from sketchfab. Thank you!

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you edit this question to include any errors that show up in the browser console?

Comment: @emackey the code compiles successfully. However, the output is not as expected. I have attached a screenshot of the output. The Box is created in the scene. However, the loaded gltf model does not show up on the screen

Comment: In your web browser, press `F12` (or use the menus to open up DevTools).  Go to the `Console` tab, and look for runtime errors.  For example, the model file itself could be getting a `404 Not Found` from the server that you're not seeing here.

Answer (score 0):

I would try importing the file and then use that variable in the SceneLoader.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33137132)